# Minikube fails to start on Windows 11 Home and Docker Desktop

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I have Windows 11 Home (which does not allow Hyper-V, only Pro edition does).
Installed WSL2 and Docker Desktop.

Installed Minikube using Chocolatey but it refused to start.
Searching on SO, I found this advice in several posts, but it failed to work.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker system prune
WARNING! This will remove:
  - all stopped containers
  - all networks not used by at least one container
  - all dangling images
  - all dangling build cache

Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
error during connect: In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run with elevated privileges to connect.: Post "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/containers/prune": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> minikube delete
* Removed all traces of the "minikube" cluster.

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> minikube start --driver=docker
* minikube v1.25.2 on Microsoft Windows 11 Home 10.0.22000 Build 22000
* Using the docker driver based on user configuration

X Exiting due to PROVIDER_DOCKER_VERSION_EXIT_1: "docker version --format -" exit status 1: error during connect: In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run with elevated privileges to connect.: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/version": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.
* Documentation: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/docker/
```

Comment: What part of *the docker client must be run with elevated privileges to connect* is unclear?

Comment: @KenWhite I did run it in a windows powershell with administrator privileges

Comment: That's not possible, or you wouldn't have gotten that error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I thought of trying to have *Docker Desktop* already running **before** I start minikube.

From the Windows Start menu, I ran *Docker Desktop in Administrator mode*.

Now I ran the command again
to remove old stuff,

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> minikube delete
* Removed all traces of the "minikube" cluster.
```

and now specify the docker driver

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> minikube start --driver=docker
* minikube v1.25.2 on Microsoft Windows 11 Home 10.0.22000 Build 22000
* Using the docker driver based on user configuration
* Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
* Pulling base image ...
    > gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase: 379.06 MiB / 379.06 MiB  100.00% 10.23 MiB p
* Creating docker container (CPUs=2, Memory=3000MB) ...
* Preparing Kubernetes v1.23.3 on Docker 20.10.12 ...
  - kubelet.housekeeping-interval=5m
  - Generating certificates and keys ...
  - Booting up control plane ...
  - Configuring RBAC rules ...
* Verifying Kubernetes components...
  - Using image gcr.io/k8s-minikube/storage-provisioner:v5
* Enabled addons: storage-provisioner, default-storageclass
* Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube" cluster and "default" namespace by default
```

Now verify minikube status

```bash
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> minikube status
minikube
type: Control Plane
host: Running
kubelet: Running
apiserver: Running
kubeconfig: Configured
```

I don't know kubernetes as I am learning it, but it appears to have worked. I hope this will be useful to someone so they do not have to go off and spend $99 to upgrade to Windows Pro - as I was going to do if this did not work.

**Update**: Here is a link with more details [How to run Kubernetes on Windows 11](https://juwo.blogspot.com/)

Comment: Thank's alot for this answer. It saves my hours of research...

Comment: @Posio if it helped you then consider an upvote for  the question